Extracting music from APK file NOT working
just trying to extract music from a game called Mini TD 2.
I extracted the folder using apktool and searched for the terms: mp3, ogg, wav, music, media, song and I didn't find any music files used in the game. I find sharedassets0.resource file, but not sure what is really is.
Is it possible to extract this way? Am I missing something?
The APK file is here. APK
The extracted output from apktool is here. Output

This game looks like created with unity framework, and all the data inside is encoded. I didn't extract such a data myself, but this tutorial looks reasonably good starting point: https://www.vg-resource.com/thread-31141.html .
